# Using an extra mock simply to take advantage of the behaviour observation tooling

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocks, integration-testing

I'm writing integration for a project, but our framework doesn't provide any ability to inject dependencies, so I've written tests with a unit testing framework (GTest) and used a mock (GMock) in an odd way simply to leverage its behaviour obverving functions.  I have a python script to run it, it all works, but, is there a better approach I should be taking?

```
/** Class that exists simply to provide stubs for callbacks */
class Monitor
{
 public:
  virtual auto subscribe() -> void {}
};

/** Mocking the ClientMonitor in order to leverage the Mocking tools, i.e.
 * EXPECT_CALL.Times, etc. */
class MockMonitor
{
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD1(subscribe, void());
};

TEST_F(Test, RECEIVE_PROXY_STATUS_EVENT_AVAILABLE)
{
  using ::testing::_;
  MockMonitor cm;

  // Listen for when the service event changes.
  auto const subscription_status = proxy_->getPayloadEvent().subscribe(
    [&cm](int64_t id, std::string const& payload) {
      cm.subscribe();
    });

  EXPECT_CALL(cm, subscribe());

  std::cout << "Waiting " << response_window_.count() << " ms for event..." << std::endl;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(response_window_);
  std::cout << "Done waiting\n";
  return;
}
```

This is an integration test so I actually want the communication to work, and there's no way I can see when I go through the code to actually mock it "normally", *i.e.*

if I derive `proxy_` and override `getProxyStatusEvent()`, I could  return a mock (in this case it would be something complex like `CommonAPI::FNV::FNVEvent<PayloadEvent, CommonAPI::Deployable< int32_t, CommonAPI::FNV::IntegerDeployment >, CommonAPI::Deployable< std::string, CommonAPI::FNV::StringDeployment >>`, but then that class has its own private signal handler, *etc*..

So, basically, because the lack of injection, I'd have to create some complex mocks based on internal code that could change at any time.. not a good solution even if possible.

Thus, the solution I wrote above seems to acheive my goals quite simply

- It only tests public api methods
- It's small
- It's flexible

It does seem odd however to create a mock of a dummy class simply to get functions like `EXPECT_CALL`.  Is there a better approach I could be taking?

Also, for context, I'm using GTest again simply for the tools it provides, i.e. test fixtures, command line parsing of test naems, the asserts, *etc*.  This could easily work without GTest.